# Joining tables using primary keys LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I'm trying to join tables by primary keys using the PrimaryKey method (the ID column is the primary key in both tables). But at the end I get an empty table. Tell me how to make the request correct?

**clientDT**:

| ID | name | city |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | New York |
| 2 | Jacob | Los Angeles |
| 3 | William | Chicago |
| 4 | Ethan | San Francisco |

**orderDT**:

| ID | order_number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123547 |
| 2 | 568688 |
| 3 | 89779 |

As a result, I expect to see a table like this:

| name | order_number | city |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 123547 | New York |
| Jacob | 568688 | Los Angeles |
| William | 89779 | Chicago |

My code:

```
var result = from client in clientDT.AsEnumerable()
             join orders in orderDT.AsEnumerable()
                  on clientDT.PrimaryKey equals orderDT.PrimaryKey
             select new 
                    {
                        Name = client.Field <string> ("name"),
                        City = client.Field <string> ("city"),
                        Order_number = orders.Field <string> ("order_number")                      
                      
                    };
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("city", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("order_number", typeof(string));
            foreach(var row in result)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { row.Name, row.City, row.Order_number});
            }
            
result_DT  = dt;
```

Comment: Have you checked if the Type of result is what you expect or if it is enumerable? Also why do you cast `clientDT` and `orderDT` to enumerable? Also try to insert a breakpoint to see if result has data, before you itterate over it

Comment: `on clientDT.PrimaryKey equals orderDT.PrimaryKey` replace with `on clients.PrimaryKey equals orders.PrimaryKey`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I think you mean `on client.PrimaryKey`... Also, feels like this should at least cause a warning if not an error from the C# compiler.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I get what you are gunning for, but in this case client and orders are of type DataRow, meaning that they have no PrimaryKey attribute

Comment: @SMSTJ, you are right. Missed that, never used DataTable post query processing.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv But in my mind you are correct about what line is causing the trouble. I think we can achive what you were trying to do in the not pretty but working way of replacing it with `on client[clientDT.PrimaryKey[0]] equals orders[orderDT.PrimaryKey[0]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its actually quite simple. The problem is that you try to compare all primary keys.

The `table.PrimaryKey` property will return a collection of all columns that make up the key. So what you are doing is comparing if a List containing one column is equal to another List containing a column, which is false, since they contain different columns. You need to orient yourself along your created rows. So this is the best I can give you at the moment. Its not really pretty but it gets the job done

```
var result = from client in clientDT.AsEnumerable()
             join orders in orderDT.AsEnumerable()
                  on client[clientDT.PrimaryKey[0]] equals orders[orderDT.PrimaryKey[0]]
             select new
                    {
                        Name = client.Field<string>("name"),
                        City = client.Field<string>("city"),
                        Order_number = orders.Field<string>("order_number")
                    };

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("city", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("order_number", typeof(string));

foreach (var row in result)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { row.Name, row.City, row.Order_number });
}
```

The secret lies in this line

```
on client[clientDT.PrimaryKey[0]] equals orders[orderDT.PrimaryKey[0]]
```

To try and explain it: your client and your orders are rows. From these rows we can get the value of a column, in our case we need the value of the column containing the PK which in our case is just one column which makes things nice.

So our primary key column is `orderDT.PrimaryKey[0]` and to get the value of it in the individual rows during the request we do `orders[orderDT.PrimaryKey[0]]` and we are done.